# Cos'è "una fame caína"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata* di Beppe Fenoglio, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto:

> Be’, a parte mio fratello, io dico che dovremmo pensare un po’ di piú a
>   quelli di noi che son finiti in Germania. Ne hai mai sentito parlare una volta che è una? Mai uno che si ricordi di loro. Invece dovremmo, dico io, tenerli un po’ piú presenti. Dovremmo schiacciare un po’ di piú l’acceleratore anche per loro. Ti pare? Si deve stare tremendamente male dietro un reticolato, si deve fare una **fame caína**, e c’è da perdere la ragione.

Non capisco del tutto bene il significato di "caína" nell'ultima frase. Ho cercato il vocabolo "caíno" in alcuni dizionari, ma appare sempre come un sostantivo. Qui invece sembra usarsi come aggettivo. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: cos'è esattamente "una fame caína"?

Comment: Il significato (figurato) potrebbe essere quello di una fame paragonabile alla sofferenza provata da Caìno dopo l'uccisione di Abele e il riprovero di Dio.

Comment: Sospetto che intenda una *fame da cani*

Comment: @DenisNardin: Ma allora sarebbe una "fame canina" e non una "fame caìna", no?

Comment: Adesso mi sono accorta che il Treccani (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/caino/) menziona che può essere anche un aggettivo. Potrebbe essere fame "senza cuore", cioè quelli che provocano tale fame sono senza cuore?

Comment: @Charo Sì, ma mi posso immaginare che nel parlato la "n" sia omessa. Un'alternativa è che il nome *Caino* venga utilizzato come rafforzativo, senza alcun particolare significato (più o meno qualsiasi parola dalla connotazione negativa può venire usata in questo modo...)

Comment: Il Treccani fa l'esempio "questa schiatta caina" (Fazio degli Uberti), ma non capisco cosa significhi.

Comment: A orecchio direi che si riferisca all'aggettivo che hai trovato, col senso letterale di “fratricida” (e quindi traditore etc.) come Caino, e qui usato semplicemente per rafforzare il senso di una fame estrema, come quando si dice “un freddo boia” e simili.

Comment: Nell'espressione "schiatta caina", "caina" significa "traditrice".

Comment: @Benedetta:  E cos'è "schiatta"?

Comment: @Charo La "schiatta" è la "stirpe", la "discendenza", persone che hanno un'origine comune.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nella *Commedia* di Dante, la Caìna è una delle parti più inferiori dell'Inferno, dove le pene sono terribili (vi sono puniti i traditori dei parenti, ed è il luogo che "attende" l'uccisore di Paolo e Francesca, secondo quanto Francesca stessa racconta a Dante nel V canto dell'*Inferno*). Potrebbe quindi essere qui un sinonimo espressivo e forte di "infernale", "terribile".

Comment: *Caìna attende chi vita ci spense*, qui la citazione è d'obbligo!

Comment: Adesso che ho letto l'*Inferno* di Dante, posso capire meglio tutte queste cose. Peccato che non si tratti dell'Antenora, dove si trova il conte Ugolino, personaggio che incarna la fame estrema.